# Role Provider: How To?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm creating my on membership and role provider with entity framework. I Have found plenty of information on creating custom membership providers but am struggling to find any good information or tutorials on role providers. I have found a few examples with a one to many relationship to the user but I would like to find a tutorial which explains how to create a many to many relationship between the user and the role like the default membership set-up. Any advice or pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to RoleProviders, please take a look at [Building a MVC2 Template, Part 9, Adding a Custom Role Provider](http://erictopia.com/2010/05/building-a-mvc2-template-part-9-adding-a-custom-role-provider/)

Hope this helps,

Matt